# Why datatables use ".row().remove()" to remove one of the lines,but multiple lines have been deleted?

Tags: jquery, html, datatables

I use this [code](https://jsfiddle.net/3xgbjk8t/2/) to test my add line and delete line.
The core code is ：

```
$(function(){      
    $("#table_reach_condition_appoint input").on("blur",function(e){
            var oTable = $("#table_reach_condition_appoint");
            eEle = '';
            var target = e.target;
            oTr = $(target).closest('tr');
            if(oTr.index() == oTable.find('tbody tr').last().index())
            {
                eEle = oTr.clone(true);
                if(
                $.trim($("#table_reach_condition_appoint tbody tr:last td input:eq(0)").val())!=""
                &&
                $.trim($("#table_reach_condition_appoint tbody tr:last td input:eq(1)").val())!=""
                &&
                $.trim($("#table_reach_condition_appoint tbody tr:last td input:eq(2)").val())!=""
                )
                {
                    oTable.append(eEle);
                    $("#table_reach_condition_appoint tbody tr:last input").val("");
                }
            }
            setRowNumber("#table_reach_condition_appoint");
        });

    var table_reach_condition_appoint_datatable = $("#table_reach_condition_appoint").DataTable({
        "paging": false,
        "bFilter": false,
        "bInfo" : false,
        "searching": false,
    } );

  $('#table_reach_condition_appoint').on('click', '.deleteRow', function () {
        var row = $(this).closest("tr"); 
        var nRow = row[0];
        table_reach_condition_appoint_datatable
        .row( $(this).parents('tr') )
        .remove()
        .draw();
        setRowNumber("#table_reach_condition_appoint");
        });

});

function setRowNumber(tableID){
    var rowLength = $(tableID+" tbody tr").length;
    for(var i = 1;i<=rowLength;i++){
        $(tableID +" tbody tr:eq("+(i-1)+") td:first").text(i);
    }
}
```

At first line,I entered text in the three input box,like this:[image]

Then automatically added a new line like this:
[image]

Then I entered text at the second line:
[image]

Then automatically added the third line like this:
[image]

Then I entered text at the third line:
[image]

When I click the "X" at the third line like this:
[image]

There is only one line left like this:
[image]

This is wrong. I just want to delete the line I clicked.And if there is only one line, can't delete it,how to modify my js?

Comment: Can you please share your HTML as well, thus forming a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @venkat.yerr ,can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself.Add onclick event to `href`.

Modify code like this:

Html code:

```
<td> <a href="###" class="deleteRow" onclick="delRow(this,'#table_reach_condition_appoint')">X</a></td>
```

js code:

```
function delRow(obj,tablId) {
    if ($(tablId+" tbody tr").length>1){
    $(obj).parent().parent().remove();
    setRowNumber(tablId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems `DataTables` doesn't realize the lines that you added by Jquery append.

You have to use `DataTables` API instead of `Jquery` append().

The Api:

https://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html

My solution:

https://jsfiddle.net/3xgbjk8t/28/